# Do I really have to pay for seat selection in online check-in of Pegasus Airlines?

Tags: tickets, seating, check-in, pegasus-airlines

I'm trying to online check-in my flight with Pegasus Airlines and whenever I try to change my automatically allocated seat it shows that I have to pay extra cash. This even happens for regular seats and not exit/added value...

Is it really this way with Pegasus Airlines or am I missing something?

In your opinion, is it worth it then to check-in online? Or to just wait up to the airport check-in desk?

Comment: Why not use your allocated seat?..

Comment: We're more than one passenger each traveling on the same flight but with different booking references (we booked separately) so we want to sit together..

Comment: I think it's quite common for airlines to charge extra to select different seats when checking in online.  I have paid for different seats on a few occasions on different airlines.  I have also found it's often possible to select different seats when checking-in in person by asking the check-in agent - I've never had to pay then, however as it's usually closer to the time of the flight the available seats are limited

Comment: Be aware that some low-cost carriers charge you 75$ or more if you don’t do the online checkin. Per person. That’s a pretty good reason to do it. Check your details before you don’t do it. - Lesson: the cheapest flight does not necessarily rest in the cheapest trip...

Comment: @TripleNipple : You won't (necessarily) get automatically assigned seats together *even if you make a single booking*.  We certainly didn't on recent flights with Ryanair Stansted-Basel.

Comment: This is yet another case of "You get what you pay for".

Comment: @Muzer: ... with a slight undertone of "You pay extra for what formerly used to be included at the minimum service level."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you are seeing a race to the bottom in the civil aviation sector - the "minimum service level" used to be a lot more expensive than what you currently pay.  Its been going this way for decades, and we haven't seen the end yet.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the basic "scams" of modern life.

Comment: @Moo: Not only in the civil aviation sector. And yes, I know prices have indeed lowered, which is why I wrote thete is only a "slight undertone", in contrast to some other products that exhibit the same shrinkage of included features but do not become cheaper in return.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yup - I think these days you simply are "getting less for less"...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Yes**, you do, and sitting next to your friends and family is [explicitly listed as a reason to do it](https://www.flypgs.com/en/travel-services/flight-services/seat-selection).

[image]

For what it's worth, this is fairly common for low-cost carriers.

Comment: just booked with Volotea and all seats are an "extra" with prices ranging from about €8 to €25. I find it quite annoying especially as these 'extras' (seats, snacks, baggage, check-in etc) only get added after you have entered all the details of those flying. So it's very time consuming when comparing different carriers.

Comment: @paul that's the whole point. They wan't you to be sold on using their service via comparing the _absolute lowest fare_ that makes the makes them the least profit, then they bump up those profit figures by selling you stuff you probably expected in the first place. By making it difficult for you to compare _final_ prices vs the _initial_, low value, crappy price they come out looking more favourable, or by the time you realise they're not as good as you first hoped they're hoping you've sunk enough time in to filling out their forms that you don't care about the difference.

Comment: @JamesTrotter - I realise that which is why I always register with fake names and email addresses in the vain hope that it annoys them as much as they annoy me ;-)

Comment: @paul there is always a free seat, which is the seat allocated to you by the system. I've never had to pay anything extra as I don't care about where I sit on short flights.

Comment: What @JonathanReez syas.   If you are alone on a two hour internal flight, who cares?  I have my seat number allocated and cannot be bumped by overbooking, the airline moves my body from city X to city Y and I arrive with $$ left over from not buying stuff I didn't need.

Comment: @JamesTrotter: You don't need to see it so negatively. The reality is that the price *should* scale with how much you demand from them. It's amazing that they're willing to make that happen. That way those who demand less can get a better price.